# How to get make to fail if generation of a required include passes but the file is not actually created

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile that is erroneously generating a required makefile include file.  The included file does not initially exist, but there is a rule to make it.  The rule runs successfully, but because of a bug, the required include file is not created where expected (and thus make is unable to include it).  However, instead of make failing (due to the fact that the file still can't be included), make completes successfully.

The following is my makefile1.mak file.

```
include myfile.mak

default:
    @echo hi

myfile.mak:
    @echo hello
```

When I execute 'make -f makefile1.mak', I get:

```
makefile1.mak:1: myfile.mak: No such file or directory
hello
hi
```

Of course, I finally figured out that my code to generate myfile.mak was not generating it correctly, but the actual makefiles that I'm using are 100s of lines long, so we didn't notice that the include wasn't happening for quite a while (it was a very subtle build issue that was introduced).

So, my question is - is there any way to get make to fail on the above example?

Comment: How does your rule succeed despite failing to create the file? Fixing the rule is probably the better line of attack since a missing include is only an error if the rule to generate it fails: "Only after it has tried to find a way to remake a makefile and failed, will make diagnose the missing makefile as a fatal error."

Comment: This applies to all targets (not only include files) by design - if the recipe succeeds then make blindly "believes" that the target was created successfully. If that could be an issue, you should check for target existence manually, as @Beta proposes.

Comment: @Matt, thanks for indicating that it was by design, though that seems like a bad behavior for the case of includes.  I.e. if I don't use '-include', I'm telling make that the file MUST be included, so if the include file can't be included even after it's supposedly rebuilt, then make should not be able to progress (because I told it that it MUST include a file that it can't include).  That being said, I understand this is the way make is and I'll have to accept it.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, thanks for the responses.  However, my point was that I didn't know that the recipe was incorrect and the build continued.  If I had known the recipe was incorrect, I would have corrected it :-).

Answer (score 3):

Add a line to the rule:

```
myfile.mak:
    do various things to build myfile.mak
    test -f $@
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my comments above, if I had known that the recipe was incorrect, I would have written the recipe correctly in the first place :-).  In my opinion, adding the 'test' to every target should not be necessary.

Comment: @Brett: *Every* target? I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: If in my build process I have 100 different recipes used to build 100 different makefile include targets, I would need to put that check into every one of those 100 different targets for makefile includes.  Whereas, in my opinion, if I tell make to include a given file (and not ignore if the file exists by using the '-' syntax), it should fail if it can't include a file I told it to not silently include.  I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: @Brett: There is a way to get the effect you want without adding commands to those rules, but as far as I know there is no way to get Make to behave the way you think it ought to.